# PHP upgrades from 5.3.2 to 5.3.6

Tags: php

I am using Ubuntu 10.04. And I want to upgraded my php version.
When i am upgrading my PHP version(5.3.2 to 5.3.6) but After every updation Its show PHP version 5.3.2..

Edit:: I have checked "Ubuntu repository", PHP 5.3.6 is not avalable. :(

Comment: This is off-topic for Stack Overflow. Recommending it be moved to Server Fault.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First add the following lines to the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/php5-ppa.list` file using your favourite editor.

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/nginx/php5/ubuntu maverick main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/nginx/php5/ubuntu maverick main
```

Then run the following command to add a key for the newly added repositories:

```
sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com 00A6F0A3C300EE8C
```

After that you can update Ubuntu's software and upgrade PHP:

```
aptitude update
aptitude full-upgrade
```

Comment: I'm looking to upgrade my LTS Ubuntu 10.04 server for php > 5.3.2.  10.04 is called "lucid" where 10.10 is called "maverick".  I noticed "maverick" is used in above example.  Does this mean it's just pulling the PHP repo files from maverick?  Will have be ok for lucid?

Comment: Downvoted because the answer is no longer current. There are no php5 builds in the nginx PPA anymore (as far as I could see).

Comment: An up to date way to do this  is to use ondrej's ppa, as stated below and as posted here http://askubuntu.com/questions/109404/how-do-i-install-latest-php-in-supported-ubuntu-versions-like-5-4-x-in-ubuntu-1

Comment: I got these errors: `W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/nginx/php5/ubuntu/dists/maverick/main/binary-i386/Packages.gz  404  Not Found` and `W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/nginx/php5/ubuntu/dists/maverick/main/source/Sources.gz  404  Not Found`

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using my (Ondrej's) PPA, the answer taken from another Q&A thread:
[[How do I install different (upgrade or downgrade) PHP version in still supported Ubuntu release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/109404/how-do-i-install-php-5-4-0/109544#109544])

You could use a ppa to stay up-to-date with php. I use :

[https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/php5 [image: Launchpad logo]](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/php5)

It's now on 5.4. If you want use this ppa do this:

[ppa:ondrej/php5 [image: Launchpad logo]](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/php5) ([Click here for instructions on using PPAs.](https://askubuntu.com/q/4983))

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php5
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

If you don't have add-apt-repository binary do the following:

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
```

Answer (score 1):

[Seems outdated]

I you want to upgrade Ubuntu 10.04 LTS to PHP 5.3.10, this is how I have done it:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge php*  
sudo apt-get autoremove  
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:brianmercer/php5  
sudo apt-get update  
sudo apt-get install php5 libapache2-mod-php5 php5-cli php5-cgi php5-mysql php5-gd  
sudo service apache2 restart  
sudo pecl uninstall apc  
sudo pecl install apc
```

Thanks to Brian Mercer for his PPA for php5.

Comment: JFTR Brian Mercer's php5 PPA is outdated.

Comment: I tried this, and Brian Mercer's PPA throws a 404.

Answer (score 0):

Just found how to upgrade to 5.3.5, maybe it will help you:

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:fabianarias/php5
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Thanks to http://blog.leenix.co.uk/2011/06/ubuntu-1004-lts-lucid-php-533-backport.html

```
$ php -v
PHP 5.3.5-1ubuntu7.2ppa1~lucid1 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: May 25 2011 18:51:41) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2009 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2010 Zend Technologies
```

Answer (score -1):

check this:
http://www.omaroid.com/installing-lamp-with-php-5-3-6-on-ubuntu-11-04-natty-narwhal/

Kev, The part that says: use this repository:

```
deb http://packages.dotdeb.org stable all
deb-src http://packages.dotdeb.org stable all
```

Comment: Which part of this linked article answers the OP's question which is about **upgrading** his PHP installartion.

Answer (score -2):

Unfortunately I believe you have to install PHP from source in order to get the latest version. You can get the file from php.net, and essentially follow their installation guide from their manual.