# Update PHP 5.3.2 to 5.3.3 or 5.4 on Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: upgrade, 10.04, php

I have PHP 5.3.2 on Ubuntu 10.04 LTS

```
$ php -v
PHP 5.3.2-1ubuntu4.30 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Apr 17 2015 15:01:29)
```

and I would like to upgrade PHP to at least 5.3.3 (5.4 would be better), so I read about it [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/565784/how-to-upgrade-php-version-to-the-latest-stable-released-version-lets-say-how) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56933/php-upgrades-from-5-3-2-to-5-3-6) and did the following steps:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php5-oldstable
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
$ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade php5
$ sudo apt-get install php5
```

But it will not update any packages and the PHP version is still the same.

I also tried with

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php5
```

Comment: Ubuntu 10.04 is past End Of Life.  It went End of Life on April 30, 2015.  Being that it is End of Life, it is offtopic.  To get continued support, you may wish to upgrade to AT LEAST 12.04.

Comment: @ThomasW. - you are right with that, but this is not wildly important. T. Weller could check if php 7 would work on his machine ?! - I would prefer in this situation xubuntu with xfce4 and add perl-modules (libraries) installable for php and then give this a shot with php 7 ... ?!

Comment: @dschinn1001 actually it is fairly important; an EOL release has zero support, and we don't provide support for EOL releases; at least, we don't provide support on questions asked *after* the release goes EOL.  As well, PHP 7 is *new*, and doesn't build sanely really for Lucid, which is quite old (almost 6 years old)

Comment: @ThomasW. ... fairly true, not wildly ... take care of Caesar-Calendars... they have only 333, moon-month-days ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I tried a lot more things, I think these steps using the [PHP 5.3.3 backport of Chris Lea](https://launchpad.net/~chris-lea/+archive/ubuntu/php5.3.3) solved my problem:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:chris-lea/php5.3.3
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
```

And the version is now

```
$ php -v
PHP 5.3.3-8ubuntu12~lucid1 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Jan 26 2011 20:34:21)
```

Comment: You desperately need to upgrade! It's not safe to run 10.04 anymore.